# What is the role of Send and Sync in libcore?

Tags: rust, intrinsics

`Sync` and `Send` play a big role in the `thread` API from the standard library. However, they are also included in `libcore`. Within the latter, there are a few types that implement them, but I can't find any "consumers", that is, some API that would use those traits as bounds.

Do they have some special behavior/meaning that the compiler knows about? Notice that they are lang items, so they are in some way special. `Sync` seems to be [related to statics](https://manishearth.github.io/blog/2017/01/11/rust-tidbits-what-is-a-lang-item), but the link does not go into much detail.

**TL;DR:** if `Send` and `Sync` are about thread-safety, what role do they fulfill in `libcore` where there is no notion of multi-threading? What semantics does the compiler assign to them as lang items?

Comment: The book has a section precisely on [Send and Sync](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/concurrency.html#background-send-and-sync). Is there something in it that you find unclear?

Comment: Same question, adding the API documentation for [`Send`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Send.html) and [`Sync`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Sync.html).

Comment: - *Within the latter, there are a few types that implement them, but I can't find any "consumers"* - I'd say it's a good practice to **document** thread-safety. With `Send` and `Sync`. cf. https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp09263/

Comment: @ArtemGr @Shepmaster @E_net4 I added an alternative phrasing, I hope my question is now clearer. Note that I'm specifically referring to their role _in `libcore`_.

Comment: @rvidal Let's narrow the question to one specific type that you think would be a good example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> if `Send` and `Sync` are about thread-safety, what role do they fulfill in `libcore` where there is no notion of multi-threading?

`libcore` is about setting the core concepts of the language; `Send` and `Sync` are core to the language: the compiler knows and reasons about them<sup>1</sup>.

The fact that `libcore` does not *use* multi-threading itself is orthogonal and has no incidence on this choice.

---

As an aside, do consider that just because `libcore` does not have multi-threading does not mean that one cannot built an alternative standard library on top of `libcore` that does have multi-threading. That is, after all, the purpose of separating `core` from `std`.

---

<sup>1</sup> *As mentioned by @kennytm in comments, Rust has a user-accessible mechanism to allow automatically propagating marker traits based on whether said traits are implemented by all a structure fields, or not. This is slightly insufficient for `Send` and `Sync`, though, as it does not support `&(Trait + Send)`, and therefore the compiler requires special knowledge about those two, which is why they are lang items.*

Comment: `[...] that libcore does not use multi-threading itself is orthogonal [...]` That could be the case but I suspect is not. After all they are lang items, so they _probably_ fulfill some role during compilation independent of `libstd`. Notice that the reference I linked above says explicitly so: that `Sync` is somehow required for statics ([example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=db22b27d09cf55556a2f5432dc18c698&version=nightly&backtrace=0)). Now my question is: does this _actually_ serve a purpose if you don't have threads, or is it just scaffolding for `libstd`? And what about `Send`?

Comment: - "*or is it just scaffolding for libstd*" - threads != libstd.

Comment: @rvidal: `Sync` and `Send` being lang items is what I mean by *the compiler knows them*. In order to have data-race freedom, all types must be analyzed for their `Sync` and `Send` properties, even the core types. Of course, these properties and this analysis are kinda wasted if you do not actually used multiple threads: they then serve no purpose. On the other hand, they also impose no run-time penalty and probably only a minimal compile-time penalty so it's not seen as a big deal. And now, whether you have multi-threading from libstd or *some other source*, you have data-race freedom.

Comment: @ArtemGr `threads != libstd` I am aware of that. The complete phrasing would be "scaffolding for an OS-aware std-like library that would include threads (like `libstd` itself)". I just don't have enough characters ;)

Comment: @MatthieuM. Thanks for your answer. Does that mean then that the compilation error I linked in my previous comment is somehow "spurious", if you are, say, doing bare-metal programming?

Comment: @rvidal: It seems so to me. There are rough edges around bare-metal targets still, and I would expect the ability to hint to the compiler that threading should be disabled is one of them.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Nitpick: `Send` and `Sync` remain lang items to support things like `&(Trait + Send)`. But analyzing whether a type is Send/Sync is reasoned with [auto-traits (OIBIT)](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0019-opt-in-builtin-traits.md) which doesn't need special compiler knowledge about the trait.

Answer (score 1):

[The compiler will crash if you declare a `static` variable and no `Sync` trait exists](http://manishearth.github.io/blog/2017/01/11/rust-tidbits-what-is-a-lang-item/).

After all, just because we don't have libstd's implementation of threads in play doesn't mean there's no concurrent access going on (if you're bare metal, you probably have interrupt handlers to worry about). So, for static variables to be safe, the compiler needs to know if the static variable can be safely accessed concurrently or not.